# youtube-dl: How to skip videos with unavailable fragments in playlist, but not to abort playlist downloading?

Tags: playlist, youtube-dl

I want to download a playlist of videos from [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEsfXFp6DpzTD1BD1aWNxS2Ep06vIkaeW) using youtube-dl for further offline viewing.
Some videos have unavailable fragments (but for some reason there is no problem when viewing through browser). I want to download the playlist, but skip the videos with missing fragments.

My original run was:

```
youtube-dl -if bestvideo+bestaudio PLEsfXFp6DpzTD1BD1aWNxS2Ep06vIkaeW
```

But it "freezes" at videos with missed fragments.

Later, in documentation I found this option option `--abort-on-unavailable-fragment`

But following command just aborts, when it takes 10 retries for attempt to download fragment.

```
youtube-dl --abort-on-unavailable-fragment -if bestvideo+bestaudio PLEsfXFp6DpzTD1BD1aWNxS2Ep06vIkaeW
```

I also found parameter `--skip-unavailable-fragments`, but it just skips fragments, which are unavailable and continue to download next fragment. It results in glitches in video after merging.

```
youtube-dl --skip-unavailable-fragments -if bestvideo+bestaudio PLEsfXFp6DpzTD1BD1aWNxS2Ep06vIkaeW
```

Are there any options / parameters to download the whole playlist, but as soon as there is video with missed fragment: skip that video and switch to the next video in playlist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
--abort-on-unavailable-fragment  Abort downloading when some fragment is not
                                 available
```

This will skip the video if it has unavailable fragments, taken from the readme: https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl#download-options tested on the same issue.

Comment: It aborts the download of the whole playlist, not a single video from the playlist. Tested today.

Comment: Are you on newest yt-dl? I posted it after having it fixed with that flag myself. In stdout I can see it attempting to download one that has 404 fragments and then aborts that one specific item only, continuing to download all the others in the playlist.

Comment: Works now. I don't know, what changed, but it works now.

Comment: that's for fragments not videos

Comment: @Harvey - have you read the OP, the title, the comments or tried it before posting this?

Comment: @stackbox yup i did all that

Comment: Just tried it again and it still works today (06.09.2020) on latest build (v2020.09.06) - skipping only the video that has missing fragments, downloading the rest.

Answer (score 11):

```
-i, --ignore-errors
```

This one works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the above mentioned answer but it aborts the whole playlist. I tried using -i which ignores all the errors and skips if the video is unavailable in your country. And this method works without any problems.

```
youtube-dl -i -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLx65qkgCWNJIs3FPaj8JZhduXSpQ_ZfvL'
```

1. use `--extract-audio` if you want only audio
2. use `--audio-format mp3` if you want to specify the audio format

Answer (score 0):

Update in 2021:

You can use

```
--abort-on-unavailable-fragment  --ignore-errors
```

In this way if a video have a fragment unavaible it will skip to the next whiout aborting, ignoring the abort.